# Conjugacy Class of $(2 1)$ in $S_4$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

What are the conjugacy classes of $(21)$ in $S_4$?

I think they are $\{(12),(13),(14),(23),(24),(34)\}$

But I'm not sure and the centralizer of $(12)$ is $\{(21),(34)\}$. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, conjugacy classes in $S_n$ are determined by cycle type

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Conjugation of permutations preserves cycle type, so, yes, the conjugacy class is correct.

Note that the identity is in the centraliser too. It is also closed (as it is a subgroup of $S_4$), so the product $(12)(34)$ is in there as well.

Comment: Oh right. thank you! how can i find de index of centralizer of (12) in $S_4$?

Comment: You're welcome, @KevinDuran. The index of any subgroup $H$ of a finite group $G$ is $$[G:H]=\frac{|G|}{|H|}.$$